# Swift 2.1 Замыкание

Tags: swift

Где ошибка?

```
let arrayInt = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]

func myF(array: [Int], cl:(n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Bool) -> Int {

    var number : Int

    for value in array {
        if cl(n1: number, n2: value) {
            number = value
        }
    }

    return number

}

myF(arrayInt, { cl: (n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Bool in 
    return n1 < n2
})
```

Функция принимает массив интов и клоужер и возвращает инт. Клоужер должен принимать 2 инта и возвращать да или нет. Нужно пройтись в цикле по массиву интов и сравнивать элементы с переменной используя клоужер. Если клоужер возвращает да, то вы записываете значение массива в переменную. в конце функции возвращайте переменную.

В результате получаю три ошибки:

1. consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
   myF(arrayInt, { cl: (n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Bool in
2. expected expression
   myF(arrayInt, { cl: (n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Bool in
3. contextual type for closure argument list expects 2 arguments, which cannot be implicitly ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете Swift 2.0, то в коде есть 2 ошибки.
 1. Не инициализирована переменная `number`.
 2. Небольшая ошибка с синтаксисом передачи кложура.

Я не совсем понял, чему должна быть равна `number` изначально, но попробуйте следующий код:

```
let arrayInt = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]

func myF(array: [Int], cl:(n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Bool) -> Int {

    var number : Int = 0

    for value in array {
        if cl(n1: number, n2: value) {
            number = value
        }
    }

    return number

}

myF(arrayInt, cl: { (n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Bool in
    return n1 < n2
})
```

Обратите внимание как вызывается функция `myF`: 
`myF(arrayInt, cl: {`

Comment: Благодарю подробный ответ! Теперь буду знать правильны синтаксис. Вообще задача стоит так, что 'number' должен быть 'optional'. То есть  'number = Int?'. Как быть в такой ситуации с инициализацией 'number'?

Comment: @Roman проблема в том, что в cl вы сравниваете number с другим числом. Вам в любом случае нужно начальное  значение, что бы произвести первое сравнение.

Comment: Это я понимаю. @Alexander, сапсибо еще раз! 
Хорошего дня!